# Calculate total of dynamic form rows

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a form with a dynamic add row button. One of the fields it adds is price array

> name="price[]"

The data is entered into the text field like `£100` or left empty.

At the bottom of the form I have a 'total' field.  I want it to calculate all of the price fields and give a total for all the price rows but cannot get any of the tutorials I have found to work like this.

Please can someone explain how I can do this with ajax/javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent quite a while on this as none of the tutorials I found worked.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638775/dynamic-fields-adding-for-total-each-line) helped.