# Dynamic Fields - Adding for Total - Each Line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I'm hoping someone has come across and can help.  I had a similar question posted (solved), but have had no further help with a new issue, so I thought I'd post with that question (sorry if this is taboo).

```
      <table border="1" class="autoTable">
 <tr>

<td>Description</td><td>Stocked</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Part Price</td>
<td>Hours</td>    
<td>Rate Class</td><td>Total</td><td>Approved</td><td>Add New Row</td>    
<td>Remove Row</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="description[]" id="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" size="55" class="numeric add_to_total" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />

</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  name="stocked[]" id="stocked" value="<?php echo $stocked; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total quantity" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="partPrice[]" id="partPrice" value="<?php echo $partPrice; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total part" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="hours[]" id="hours" value="<?php echo $hours; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total hours" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><select name="rate[]" id="rate" class="numeric add_to_total rate" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
<?php
    //php code here for rates
?>
</select>
</td><td><input name="total[]" id="total" size="10" class="numeric is_total" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" id="approved" value="<?php echo $approved; ?>" size="10" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><img src="img/plus.png" width="25" height="25" id="addButton" title="Add New Row" class="addRow" />
</td><td align="center"><img src="img/x.png" width="25" height="25" id="removeButton" title="Remove Row" class="delRow" />
</td></tr>
</table>
```

I use the following code to add up the total row, but it doesn't work for the second and subsequent dynamic rows.

```
$(".add_to_total").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".add_to_total").each(function() {
        var quantity = parseFloat($(".quantity").val()) || 0;
        var part = parseFloat($(".part").val()) || 0;
        var hours = parseFloat($(".hours").val()) || 0;
        var rate = parseFloat($(".rate").val()) || 0;
        total = (Number(quantity) * Number(part)) + (Number(rate) * Number(hours));
    });
    $(".is_total").val(total);
});
```

I'm hoping someone can help me...I've tried everything I can think of, and I really want to get this thing solved, and move on with my life :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm just completely missing it, but I don't see what inputs your JavaScript is supposed to be working on.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. What exactly are you looking for the total?

Comment: @WillSam If your previous question has been solved, please mark it as Accepted, by touching the green tick at the left side of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where the classes `add_to_total`, `quantity`, `part`, `hours`, `rate` or `is_total` are in your HTML, or which elements you're trying to select in your Javascript as a result...hope this helps...

***EDIT:***

Thinking about it again, it might be as a result of the newly-added rows' `add_to_total` classed elements *not* being bound to change events. Have you considered using the `.live()` / `.on()` jQuery events (depending on what version of jQuery you're using)?

http://api.jquery.com/live/ (jQuery < 1.7)

http://api.jquery.com/on/ (jQuery >= 1.7)

Maybe implemented something like this:

```
// using the .live() event...
$(".add_to_total").live('change', function(){ ... });

// using the .on() event...
$(".add_to_total").on('change', function(){ ... });
```

***EDIT:***

Haha! Hopefully the last edit! Well, considering the following code:

```
var quantity = parseFloat($(".quantity").val()) || 0;
```

This will always return the **first** `$(".quantity")`'s value, although a set of elements is actually selected...this is just the functionality of the `.val()` function in jQuery. What you're looking to do is process calculations for each of the rows, like you said. Simplified, you need to get the `TR` element for the current `add_to_total`, only focus on its children, then move on.

Obviously this is processing a LOT of unnecessary calculations, and I would suggest rather adding a class to each of the rows which need to have calculations run on them and loop through them directly rather:

```
<tr class="dynamic_row"> ... </tr>
```

Then in the Javascript:

```
$(".add_to_total").on('change', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".dynamic_row").each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var quantity = parseFloat(row.find(".quantity").val()) || 0;
        var part = parseFloat(row.find(".part").val()) || 0;
        var hours = parseFloat(row.find(".hours").val()) || 0;
        var rate = parseFloat(row.find(".rate").val()) || 0;
        total = (Number(quantity) * Number(part)) + (Number(rate) * Number(hours));
    });
    row.find(".is_total").val(total);
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ya, that was dumb...playing with the code when I posted.  This is what I have been using for the table with the classes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, what I can't seem to do, is when I use my dynamic trigger to add another row to the table, using the jquery.table.addrow.js plugin (http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php), I can't get the total.  I can only seem to calculate the first row, that is there when the page loads.  I need to find a way to have the jquery to add the totals on each row...

Comment: Re: Edit 2.  The calculation can't be done until the fields are entered on each (additional) dynamic row.  There is no way to predict what will come next, or how many rows there will be.  I tried a regular onchange function, but it doesn't interpret the array of values that is generated with the dynamic row.  I don't care which field it has to be (prefer all of them, but will take what I can get) to generate the calculation.

Comment: Re: Edit 3.  Thank YOU for sticking with me.  I did make a change after I posted my last comment.  I changed the first row of my 'function' to this: $(".add_to_total").live("change",function() {
Now, I get a calculation in each dynamic row total, but it is the value of the first row's total.  If I can get it to calculate it's own row's values, then I'm golden.  Any thoughts on how to make that happen?  I'm using jquery 1.7.1.

Comment: Yes, per your edit, the first suggestion, using live, will add only the same value as the first row total to all subsequent rows.  On doesn't give me any value in the second or subsequent rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your code samples don't add any rows, including the first.  I tried them also with the `code` .live('change', `code` option, to no avail.  I appreciate all your help, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  I've been fighting with this for days, so as sloppy as it may be for processing unnecessary calculations, I can live with it.  ;)

Comment: EUREKA!  I think I got it.  I changed Chris' second suggestion.  I'll see if I can answer my own question with the code...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris' suggestion, I moved the `row.find(".is_total").val(total);`
 associated to the row.  In his suggestion, he had it outside the element where it was declared, so I *think* the function didn't know what we were talking about.

I also changed the 
`$(".add_to_total").change(function() {`
to:
`$(".add_to_total").live('change',function() {`
 in order to make it function on each occurance, as I understand it from his Edit #3.

So the final function to calculate the totals is:

```
$(".add_to_total").live('change',function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".dynamic_row").each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var quantity = parseFloat(row.find(".quantity").val()) || 0;
        var part = parseFloat(row.find(".part").val()) || 0;
        var hours = parseFloat(row.find(".hours").val()) || 0;
        var rate = parseFloat(row.find(".rate").val()) || 0;
        total = (Number(quantity) * Number(part)) + (Number(rate) * Number(hours));
        row.find(".is_total").val(total);
    });
});
```

Since I'm a relatively newcomer to Stack Overflow, I'm not sure how to give him any credit, other than to accept his as an accepted answer, and to uptick the Useful option.

Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Pretty much, thanks for the acceptance! Glad to have helped! I'm going to edit my answer to make it more relevant to others who come across this in searches... :)